# Changing the action on submiting a form

Tags: jquery, jqueryform

First I will try to explain what I want to do:
I have a system that creates dynamically subdomains and each one of them have their own database and set of rules. In my main page, I have a login form that should be use to access the correct subdomain based on the given email. That is alright but what I need is this:
after check which is the correct subdomain, how the script should change the form action to login and redirect to the given subdomain?

My script code is like this:

```
function myJson(url, postData) {
        Jsondata = $.ajax({
            url : url,
            data : postData,
            type : 'post',
            dataType : 'json',
            async : false
        }).responseText;
        return jQuery.parseJSON(Jsondata);
    }
    $(function() {
        function beforeRequest(formData, jqForm) {
            var url = jqForm.attr('action');
            var data = jqForm.serialize();
            var jsonData = myJson(url, data);
            if (jsonData.success == true) {
                jqForm.attr('action',jsonData.loginUrl);
            } else {
                $("#login-form > .error-tooltip").find('span').empty().text(jsonData.msg).end().fadeIn(300);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        $("#login-form").submit(function() {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                beforeSubmit : beforeRequest
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
```

If there's a way to do this without the plugin ajaxForm (without a plugin at all) would be much obliged.
This script that I made, it makes the validation, changes the form action, but it does not redirect.
 What am I missing?

Comment: can you redirect using window.location?

Answer (score 0):

can't you simply redirect in the `if` block like

```
if (jsonData.success == true) {
 location.href='your sub domain to redirect to';
```

Comment: but I want the user to login into his respective subdomain, redirecting wont send post data

Comment: @Palantir, but once you got a correct subdomain based on email it should mean that the user is already logged in, right? why should they have to log in twice?

Comment: It doesn't login twice, that's precisely the point, the validation is meant to figure it where it should login.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, thanks to a friend of mine. The problem was the login in the subdomain, it responds with a 302 status, and success on jquery ajax expects only status 200, that's the code that works:

```
$("#login-form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr("action");
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url : url,
                data : data,
                type : 'post',
                dataType : 'json',
                beforeSend : function() {
                    $("#login-form > .error-tooltip").fadeOut(300);
                },
                success:function(jsonData){
                    if(jsonData.sucsess == true){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: jsonData.loginSite,
                            data:data,
                            type:'post',
                            complete:function(){
                                window.location = jsonData.site;    
                            }
                        })
                    }else{
                        $("#login-form > .error-tooltip").find('span').empty().text(jsonData.msg).end().fadeIn(300);
                    }
                }
            })
        })
```